# How to export all hardcoded strings to Strings.xml

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

If there is any eclipse extension that generate string in Strings.xml by click on warning that eclipse do? 
Because it is very tedious :/

Or maybe there are other ways to export the strings?

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse you can press alt + shift + a and then s to extract the selected String.

Or, as pointed out in the post by user1920666 in the menu: 
Refractor -> Android -> Extract Android String

Answer (score 1):

Select your String

Refractor on eclipse tabs -> Android -> Extract Android String

or

Alt + SHFT + A and then S